# Realm give stale results in multi thread scenario

Tags: android, realm

## Scenario

I have a typical UI thread and worker thread scenario. I did some work and write the result to realm in worker thread. The result is a simple RealmObject with some String fields. Once this is done, I send an event on UI thread to my Activity (using Otto event bus) to report that the work is completed.

Upon receiving event in my Activity, I query for the result and the String fields were not updated with the write value.

On worker thread:

```
// Did some work. Got some result

// Write to realm
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            MyResult result = realm.where(MyResult.class)
                .equalTo("id", 1)
                .findFirst();
            result.someString = "hello world";
        }
    });
} finally {
    if(realm != null){
        realm.close();
        realm = null;                    
    }
}

//Post job done event on Otto bus
uiThreadBus.post(new JobDoneEvent());
```

On Activity:

```
// Upon received JobDoneEvent
MyResult result = realm.where(MyResult.class)
    .equalTo("id", 1)
    .findFirst();

// result.someString is some stale value
Log.d("TAG", result.someString);
```

## What I did

I realized if i wrap the query in a transaction block then the RealmObject will be up to date when i try to print it.

```
// Upon received JobDoneEvent
MyResult result = null;
try{
    realm.beginTransaction();
    result = realm.where(MyResult.class)
        .equalTo("id", 1)
        .findFirst();
    realm.cancelTransaction();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    realm.cancelTransaction();
}    

// result.someString is up-to-date
Log.d("TAG", result.someString);
```

## Questions

1. What is the correct way to get up-to-date RealmObject? Do i have to throw them in a transaction block every time to force it to "synchronize" with worker thread? Is there a pattern I can follow?
2. What exactly does beginning a realm transaction (either through Realm#beginTransaction() or Realm#executeTransaction()) do? Does it block read/write attempt by other thread? Is there any harm in performing long operation (such as network request) in a transaction?

## Edit

Actual code:

```
// Did some work. Got some result

// Write to realm
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            User managedUser = result.payload.createOrUpdateInRealm(realm, 
                MyApplication.getPrimaryKeyFactory());

                Log.i("TAG", "updated user: " + managedUser.getId());
            }
        });
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
    }
}

//Post job done event on Otto bus
MyApplication.getBusInstance().post(new LoginEvent());



// Writing to realm method
public User createOrUpdateInRealm(@NonNull Realm realm,
                                  @NonNull PrimaryKeyFactory pkFactory) {
    User managedUser = realm.where(User.class)
            .equalTo("primary_key", pk)
            .findFirst();

    managedUser.setId(xUserId);
    return managedUser;
}


// Event receiving method in Activity
@Subscribe
public void loginEventReceived(LoginEvent event) {
    User user = mRealm.where(User.class)
        .equalTo("primary_key", mPk)
        .findFirst();

    Log.d("TAG", user.getId()); 
}
```

Comment: Try using a setSomething() method. I believe the realm proxy object uses that. Not sure, but worth trying

Comment: @Tim I used the setSomething() method in my actual code. The outcome is still the same. The example given is for illustration purpose only.

Comment: Piece of advice: post your actual code

Comment: @Tim There you go

Comment: Thanks. Btw just remove the other code. It will confuse people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm communicate with other threads using a special "listener" thread that put messages into the UI threads Looper queue. We don't provide any guarantees when this will happen as it might be delayed for a number of reasons. Otto will send a message directly, which most likely will happen before the looper message arrived. In that case the data on the UI thread will appear "stale".

It is much better to use Realm change listeners for these kinds of notifications. In that case you will be notified when the data is ready.

See also: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3427

Comment: Hi Christian thanks for the answer. What about the second question? Would transaction block read/write from another thread?

Comment: Write transactions block each other across all threads. Read transactions are never blocked (You can always access your data even if a write transaction is in progress).

Answer (score 2):

The UI thread's Realm is updated by a background daemon thread rather than a direct message to the Looper's message queue since 2.0.0

Even before 2.0.0 however, asynchronous queries delay the synchronous version updating of the results until all async queries are evaluated.

So Otto directly sending a message, and immediately expecting the UI thread to be up to date works only if you use **only** synchronous queries (`.findAll()`, `findAllSorted()`, etc.), and use Realm 1.2.0, or Realm 1.1.1, or older.

---

The canonical solution is to use `RealmChangeListener`s instead to be notified of change.

The unofficial solution is forcing the Realm to refresh itself and all its results directly, but that's messy and forces async queries to execute synchronously, so it's not really recommended.

---

As for transactions, it blocks all other threads from executing a transaction until the current one is finished. In a transaction, you always see the latest version of the Realm.